# Change completableFuture to Coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, completable-future, sceneform

https://github.com/temyco/sceneform-dynamic-textures-sample

Here is the link to github repo. I want to understand how can we convert completable future to Coroutine.

For Instance-

```
    private lateinit var renderableModel: ModelRenderable
    private lateinit var renderableFuture: CompletableFuture<ModelRenderable>
    private lateinit var materialFuture: CompletableFuture<CustomMaterial>
    private lateinit var customMaterial: CustomMaterial

renderableFuture.thenAcceptBoth(materialFuture) { renderableResult, materialResult ->
            customMaterial = materialResult
            renderableModel = renderableResult
            renderableModel.material = customMaterial.value
        }
```

How can we convert the above code snippet for the use of coroutines.

Comment: You can use a `suspendCancellableCoroutine`

Comment: Can you pls show how?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you don't really convert a future to a coroutine, because futures were already scheduled to execute in the background. If you just need to consume futures in a suspending manner to make your code synchronous, then this is really very easy:

```
suspend fun fun1() {
    renderableModel = renderableFuture.await()
    customMaterial = materialFuture.await()
    renderableModel.material = customMaterial.value
}
```

Note that in the case of `materialFuture` failure, you will get an exception only after `renderableFuture` completes.